# Prove that if X and Y are random variables (possibly on two different probability spaces) and $\tilde{X}= \tilde{Y}$, then $P_{X} = P_{Y}$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Prove that if X and Y are random variables (possibly on two different probability spaces) and $\tilde{X}= \tilde{Y}$, then $P_{X} = P_{Y}$ where $P_{X}= P(X \in B) = P(X^{-1}(B))$ is the probability distribution and $\tilde{X}: \mathbb{R} \to [0,1] $ defined by $\tilde{X}(s)= P_{X}((-\infty,s]) = P(X \leq s) $ is the distribution function.

I'm not sure exactly what has to be done here or what I may be missing?

If $\tilde{X}(s) = \tilde{Y}(s)$ and $\tilde{X}(s) = P_{X}((-\infty,s])$, $\tilde{Y}(s) = P_{Y}((-\infty,s])$, then  $P_{X}((-\infty,s]) = P_{Y}((-\infty,s])$ for all $s \in \mathbb{R}$. Since sets of the form $(-\infty,s]$ generate the Borel $\sigma$-algebra we get $P_{X} = P_{Y}$.

Comment: Say we have $\Omega = \{1,2,3,4\}$, $\mu,\nu : \mathcal P(\Omega) \to [0,1]$ such that $\mu(\{2\}) = \mu(\{1,3,4\})=\frac{1}{2}$, $\nu(\{k\})=\frac{1}{4} \forall_{k \in \{1,2,3,4\} }$, then when $\mathcal A = \{ \{1,2\} , \{2,3\} \}$ we have $\mu = \nu$ on $\mathcal A$, and $\sigma(\mathcal A) = \mathcal P(\Omega)$, but those measures aren't same on whole $\mathcal P(\Omega)$. In your example it is important that the family $\mathcal E = \{ (-\infty,s] : s \in \mathbb R \}$ is $\pi - $system, that is for $X,Y \in \mathcal E$ you have $X \cap Y \in \mathcal E$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an immediate consequence of Dynkin's $\pi - \lambda$ theorem. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynkin_system

Comment: So would I need to show $\{(−∞,]:∈ℝ\} $ is a $\lambda$-system?

Comment: @wasatar No, this is a $\pi$ system and $\{A: P_X(A)=P_Y(A)\}$ is a $\lambda$ system containing this $\pi$ system. Hence $\{A: P_X(A)=P_Y(A)\}$ hods for all Borel sets $A$.